# Is it possible to find type of an object that is derived from another object?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have classes that looks like this.

```
export A {...} export B {...} export C {...}

export type data = A | B | C;
```

Then I have an array of data like this.

```
dataArr : Array<data> ;
```

Is it possible that I use something like `type of` to check whether or not the element inside `dataArr` is `type of` `A`? or any other way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Did you try to use "type of"? What is the issue with it? I think what you can use is the keyword "instanceof", check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof, and Typescript doc https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing

Comment: Take a look at Typescript 4.9 [satisfy oerator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator). Would that suit you ?

Answer (score 1):

`typeof` only works on primitives so that wouldn't be possible. You could use a type guard to determine whether something is `A`, `B`, or `C` but keep in mind the complexity of the type guard(s) will grow and may be problematic if you have too many types for the `data` object.

A simple type guard would look like this:

```js
interface ImageTypeA {
    data: string
    width: number
    height: number
}

const isImageTypeA = (object: any): object is ImageTypeA => {
    return !!object.data
}

const myImage = {
    data: 'A',
    width: 1,
    height: 1
}

console.log(isImageTypeA(myImage) && myImage.data)
```

In this example ([playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=51&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFs4HMIBUCeADhAILIDeAUMjcgCZxhwBcyAzmFKFtbQO7A6YABasQAV3QAjaLxrCIwLMLBjJMqJQC+lSggD2IDsmBsM2PEVLIAvMgAU+qQCsICVcjgh8ASlZPXdxM2NEwcAmIyGwA+CjlkKAgwcSgQZABCdIC3MAA6BiZtXQMjMGR0fHMcWzjaekYWZAByEiaAGniBIVFkAEYOuoUlFVZeor1DNn0AGwhc6f0se1Mqy0j7CtWfZAAyHfLKsLmCuB8gA)) you can see how I've purposefully left out the type on `myImage`. If you hover over `myImage` you'll see it doesn't have a type, but after my type guard check you can see that it now does recognize that the object is this specific type. You can do various chaining here when there are multiple types like in your question though it can lead to confusing situations or hard to read code depending on how you structure the checks.

Comment: if are classes you can use instanceof, e.g. `this.data[0] instanceOf A`

Comment: Yes that is another option. I only write functional Typescript so I only provides answers using functional code.

Comment: One question, why would we want to use multiple type guard for multiple classes when we can just insert 1 string to object for identification, wouldnt that counter productive plus increase application size?

Comment: I don't want to add an identifier to every single const I create because then I have to do this (formatting is broken sadly):

`
interface A {
  name: string
  age: number
  kind: "A"
}

const b: A = { name: 'blah', age: 27, kind: 'A' }
`
So every object now needs this `kind` identifier. In addition as I noted I only write functional code, not class based. I don't care much about the increased application size of a few type guards, it's inconsequential.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a **discriminant property** to each type, and then check the type of the elements by that property. I assume `A`, `B` and `C` are like this:

```
interface A  {
    name: string; 
    age: number;
    kind: "A"
};

interface B  {
    city: string; 
    state: string;
    kind: "B"
};

interface C  {
    address: string;
    kind: "C"

};
```

Here, `kind` is a discriminant property, which shows the type of interface. In a `switch-case` you can get the types:

```
type data = A | B | C;
const dataArr: Array<data> = *value that you want to assign*; 

dataArr.forEach(item => {
    switch (item.kind) {
        case 'A':
            //item type is A
            break;
    
        case 'B':
            //item type is B
            break;
            

        case 'C':
            //item type is C
            break;
    }
});
```

---

If `A`, `B` and `C` are class:

```
class A  {
    name: string; 
    age: number;
};

class B  {
    city: string; 
    state: string;
};

class C  {
    address: string;
};
```

You can use `instanceof` keyword :

```
dataArr.forEach(item => {
    if(item instanceof A){
        //item type is A
    }
    if(item instanceof B){
        //item type is B
    }
    if(item instanceof C){
        //item type is C
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a way, but unfortunately my corporation just don't like the idea of adding an extra string to define the name of the type which defeats the whole purpose of defining class, at least thats what they say.

Comment: I added some extra explanation. Hope it can help you.